# Prepared IF block in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I was testing out MySQL's `PREPARE stmt FROM preparable_stmt;` functionality in a stored procedure and decided to try out control blocks, starting with `IF`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `testif`(t TEXT) BEGIN
    DECLARE q TEXT;
    SET @q:=CONCAT("IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ", t, ")>5 THEN");
    PREPARE query FROM @q; EXECUTE query; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
        SELECT "That's a nice table!";
        INSERT INTO ... #and other behaviour other than SELECT
    SET @q:="END IF";
    PREPARE query FROM @q; EXECUTE query; DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
END$$
```

Since it was being executed in the context of a stored procedure, I kind of expected this to work. Instead, when I `CALL testif("t1");`, I get this syntax error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1)>5 THEN' at line 1
```

which I would get if I ran the query outside of the procedure.

*For the record, I know how to make this query work without `PREPARE`ing the IF clause directly.* My question is purely out of curiosity, since I'm used to how `eval`-like functions work in other programming languages (where it executes the string as if it were hard-coded on that line). Setting variables and most other things work with `PREPARE`, but then again, they'd work outside of the procedure as well. Why doesn't this?

Comment: Try: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/956cb/1).

Comment: @wchiquito True, thanks, but say I am trying to control more complex behaviour than just `SELECT`. My code edit should have made more clear of my intent.

Comment: Your strategy should be something like: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03fd0/1). Remember that the scope of [9.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) are of the session.

Comment: @wchiquito yeah, that's how I would make it work without preparing the `IF` clause. I guess I am mostly curious about _why_ that situation outlined in the question isn't working as expected.